# In Ruby on Rails, is it possible to use stored procedures from models and during the life time of a session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to know is it possible to run stored procedure from model or controller i just need to send parameter which required insertion in database for now.. 3 different Model or table
Right now what am doing is trigger submission of two form when they complete than the last one execute as it need id of the first 2. For clientside it visible that a single form submission of all three..
My single controller which create model object of first 2 form than fill it keep the id of it to store it later with my third post as field value.. 
If you find difficult to understand what am saying than simply tell me is Stored procedure possible for me to use in Rails.

One more thing is SESSION life time is different in compared to the one we used in PHP and .NET. I mean to say that set session and destroy it is different in rails or same as other technology because i was doing it the way i used to do in PHP its not working for me.. Like i have three form (Contact, Company and Lead) triggering/post to one controller(Lead), this Lead Controller on first post save contact to Database through Model of Contact than after that on second post save company to Database what i want to do i wan to save these inserted records ID to Session so that next time or finally when on third post when controller try to save lead into Database it should have to ID's Available to be saved in Database well session didn't help me here so i have to use last inserted ID of the particular records like Contact and Company.. The thing am asking to do is not possible through Accept_Nested Attributes_Association... So kindly ell me how long session kept value in Rails
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this still applies to rails 3, but I guess it does.
http://nasir.wordpress.com/2007/12/03/stored-procedures-and-rails/
also you could take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129025/fetching-multiple-result-sets-from-mysql-stored-procedure-in-rails), if the one above does not work

Remember that Stored Procedures are not the rails-way

The session is started automatically (unlike in PHP where you have to start it explicitly) and you can access it by using `session[:my_ids] = [1, 2, 3]`.
Sessions in Rails don't have a timeout, as far as I know. They are stored and used as long as the user hasn't deleted the cookie.

Also please consider to mark answers as correct, since you haven't done that yet in any of your questions.

Comment: I mean to say that set session and destroy it is different in rails or same as other technology because i was doing it the way i used to do in PHP its not working for me..

Comment: Just edited my answer. Still it's not very different from PHP. You could also show *some* code, because "it's not working" is never a good explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Ruby on Rails web site](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/StoredProcedures):

> Stored Procedures are not “The rails
>   way”. [...]
>
> They may not be “the Rails way”, but
>   you can still pull them off (at least
>   in Windows connecting to sqlserver) if
>   you really want to by using the
>   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute()
>   statement [which basically executes
>   the raw sql you pass in].

Answer (score 0):

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leads,
  has_many :contact_company_profiles,
  has_many :companies, :through => :contact_company_profiles
end
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :leads, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :contact_company_profiles
end
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :company

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end
```

The thing i was asking is build_*. For session i already got an answer from a simon 
Thanks